# Find defined shortcuts in XFCE?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

I am using the PHPstorm IDE (java software, run with oracle java 7) which defines the shortcuts `Ctrl+F12` and `Alt+F8` which are not working.

Other shortcuts do work, so I think there might be some kind of shortcut conflict wit XFCE.

Actually nothing (no XFCE action) is happening when pressing one of these combos.

Under `Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts` none of this shorts is used.

Are there any other places which could cause shortcut problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the `Window Manager` settings, `Keyboard` tab. That has more keyboard shortcuts in addition to the ones in the keyboard application shortcuts.

On my XFCE config (xubuntu 12.10), Alt+F8 is assigned to "Stick window". Ctrl+F12 is assigned to "Workspace 12".